# C++ Address of Temporary Doesn't Cause a Build Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++03

One of my coworkers recently produced code similar to the following in VS2008:

```
class SomeClass {
    ...
};

void foo(SomeClass const *f) {
    ...
}

SomeClass bar() {
    ...
}

foo(&bar());
```

My interpretation was that this is incorrect code, since the address of the temporary returned by `bar` was being passed into `foo`.  However, if `bar` really returns an rvalue, this should produce a compile-time error.  Can someone please point me to the relevant parts of the C++ standard that specifies whether this code results in well-defined or undefined behavior?

Comment: [Doesn't compile in Ideone.](http://ideone.com/5gnOeG)

Comment: This is a quirk of (non-standard extension) of MS Visual Studio.

Comment: @RSahu Does that mean that this code is actually valid (meaning well-defined and working as intended) in Visual Studio?

Comment: @JeffG, I am not sure about the well-defined aspect of it.

Comment: Doesn't compile in g++:

     error: taking address of temporary foo(&bar());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not required to compile and should issue a diagnostic if it does as part of a nonstandard extension; turn on all warnings to see on msvc:

```
class SomeClass {};
void foo(SomeClass const *f) {}
SomeClass bar() { return SomeClass{}; }

int main()
{
    foo(&bar());
}
```

However the same would compile if a reference was used due to lifetime extension as per the standard:

```
class SomeClass {};
void foo(SomeClass const &f) {}
SomeClass bar() { return SomeClass{}; }

int main()
{
    foo(bar());
}
```

I tested these with msvc 2017, but I can confirm that disabling language extensions with `/Za` produces an error whereas with extensions it does not.

Comment: Your first example absolutely compiles in VS2008 (if you change the C++11 initialization syntax to parenthesis).  That is the exact code that I used to test my example prior to posting.

Comment: "should not compile" -- the standard requires **only** that the compiler issue "a diagnostic".

Comment: Drat, I should have included my usual second sentence: having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to compile the code, with an Implementation-specific meaning; that's the mechanism for extensions.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks. I'll have to do some reading to get it perfectly explained. Please edit the answer directly if it could use it. :)

Comment: You're fine. It's kind of subtle, but not important for most purposes. More of a language lawyer thing. The main thing for most people is to not ask "why does this clearly illegal code only give a warning when it shouldn't compile?"